# Define const on the fly

Tags: c

Can I #define constants dynamically?
I wish to get some data, loop through this data  and then assign the constant value.
To visualize what I want I'm attaching buggy code:

```
const char *a[2];
a[0] = "foo";
a[1] = "bar";


for (ix=0; ix< 2; ix++) {
  #define ix a[ix]
}
```

So I wish to have `0` as `foo`, `1` as `bar` etc.

I wish to be able to assign values in another values like this:

```
anotherArr[0] ="something";
```

but this `0` should be `foo`.
I'm trying to replace associative arrays.
Any clue?

Comment: That's not possible, because define is resolved at compile time - not at execution time.

Comment: "*Any clue?*" Perhaps pick another language?

Answer (score 4):

No. `#define` replaces the value at compile time. You want something at runtime, which doesn't work. `#define` is handled by the preprocessor, which in this case uses something like a simple search and replace.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. #define ZERO 0 basically goes through your code replacing all the ZERO's it finds to 0 before compiling. And then the code gets compiled.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, because defines are resolved at compile time - not at execution time. The pre-processor will just replace every occurence of your define *before* it gets compiled with whatever you have defined there. If a line contains as first character a `#` (or only whitespaces before) it is passed to the [preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor) as directive.

You want to be able to write something like `anotherArr["foo"] = "bar";` right?
In C++ you could just use std::map for this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> map;
map["foo"] = "bar";
```

But to solve your problem in C you would need something else, because there is no standard data structure to do something like that.
But what you probably can use there is a hashtable - i.e. http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/index.html

```
#include <string.h>  /* strcpy */
#include <stdlib.h>  /* malloc */
#include <stdio.h>   /* printf */
#include "uthash.h"
struct my_struct {
  char name[10];             /* key (string is WITHIN the structure) */
  int id;
  UT_hash_handle hh;         /* makes this structure hashable */
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  const char **n, *names[] = { "joe", "bob", "betty", NULL };
  struct my_struct *s, *tmp, *users = NULL;
  int i=0;
  for (n = names; *n != NULL; n++) {
    s = (struct my_struct*)malloc(sizeof(struct my_struct));
    strncpy(s->name, *n,10);
    s->id = i++;
    HASH_ADD_STR( users, name, s );
  }
  HASH_FIND_STR( users, "betty", s);
  if (s) printf("betty's id is %d\n", s->id);

  /* free the hash table contents */
  HASH_ITER(hh, users, s, tmp) {
    HASH_DEL(users, s);
    free(s);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The synatx is a Little bit different here - but I think it can solve the Problem you tried to solve with a dynamically `#define` at runtime.

Comment: Nitpicking? "*If a line contains as first character a # (or only whitespaces before) it is passed to the preprocessor.*" this it not correct. The whole content of a file being pre-processed is passed to the pre-processor.

Comment: Well, of course the whole file is scanned to replace defined pre-processor macros then. But only lines begining with a '#' are passed to the pre-processor as directive. I will change the wording, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, `#define` is a *pre-processor* construct: there is no code or compiler action involved.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on current answers, we can take a look at the source code *after preprocessing* using `gcc -E`

```
guido@solid:~$ cat a.c
const char *a[2];
a[0] = "foo";
a[1] = "bar";


for (ix=0; ix< 2; ix++) {
#define ix a[ix]
}
guido@solid:~$ gcc -E a.c 
# 1 "a.c"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "a.c"
const char *a[2];
a[0] = "foo";
a[1] = "bar";


for (ix=0; ix< 2; ix++) {

}
```

Here you can see that after preprocessing the loop is now empty, meaning the compiler **wont even know** about that #define you just tried to get away with :).